# An imo shortlist algebra question

Tags: functions, contest-math, functional-equations

> Find all functions $f:(0,\infty)\to (0,\infty)$  such that :
>   $$\frac{(f(w))^2 + (f(x))^2}{f(y^2) + f(z^2)} =\frac{w^2+x^2}{y^2+z^2} $$ for all positive real numbers $x,y,w,z$ satisfying $wx = yz$.

When I saw this question I was just blown away. Can anybody please explain the answer in detail?

Comment: @AdityaSaran Please check my editing. Is it correct?

Comment: It seems that $f(x)=ax$ is one of the potentials solutions

Comment: I have also edited some parts

Comment: What have you tried? Questions of the form 'Problem, I have no clue, please provide detailed answer' are in general not well received here.

Comment: Also, this is “just” an old IMO shortlist question. You can read their solutions on aops or on the official website of the IMO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is from the 2008 shortlist:
[image]

Comment: I have seen it but couldn't undertand it. Can you please explain it.

Comment: Specify where exactly do you have problems?

Comment: When we choose z = 1 how we get w = $\frac{y}{x}$

Comment: Because of in  $wx=yz$ when you put $z=1$...